# Why is my random integer variable not refreshing?

Tags: python, variables, random

Well, I am working on Python 2.7 and have a bug in my program...
Why is the `random.randint()` variable not refreshing, i.e, not changing its value each time the loop is executed?
Here is my code....

```
import random
handsattack = random.randint(5,10)
userhealth = 1000
while userhealth > 0:
   userhealth -= 30
   y = raw_input("Press enter to display the value of handsattack.. ")
   print(handsattack)
```

Comment: Move the call to randint() inside your while loop

Comment: Python-2.7 is EOL. Please upgrade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason it should change - you only assign the variable outside of the loop. The value will not change each time you reference it, just when you assign a value to it (i.e. when it's on the left side of `=`).

Moving the random determination into the loop will make it create a new random value for each iteration:

```
userhealth = 1000

while userhealth > 0:
   handsattack = random.randint(5,10)
   userhealth -= 30
   y = raw_input("Press enter to display the value of handsattack.. ")
   print(handsattack)
```